# Personalizar gráfico (scatter) con HighCharts en R

Tags: r, highcharts

Intento personalizar un gráfico tipo "scatter" con "HighCharts" en R para utilizarlo con rMarkDown y generar una salida html y pdf. Hasta ahora he podido parcialmente configurar.

```
hc <- dfo %>%
 hchart(
  type = "scatter",
  hcaes(
   x = dfo$`Esfuerzo`,
   y = dfo$`Umbral`,
   size = dfo$`Relevancia` * 100,
   group = dfo$`Municipio`
   ),
  tooltip = list(
   valueDecimals = 2,
   valueSuffix = " %"
  ),
  dataLabels = list(
   enabled=TRUE, 
   format='{y:.2f}',
   style = list(fontSize = "16px"),
   color = "#666666"
  )
 ) %>%
 hc_title(
  text = "Compromiso",
  style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "28px")
 ) %>%
 hc_subtitle(
  text = "",
  align = "center",
  style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "18px")
 ) %>%
 hc_xAxis(
  labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
  title = list(
   text = "Esfuerzo",
   style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "20px")
  ),
  plotLines = list(
   list(label = list(text = ""),
        color = "#FF4040",
        width = 3,
        value = median(dfo$`Esfuerzo`)
   )
  )
 ) %>% 
 hc_yAxis(
  labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
  title = list(
   text = "% Umbral", 
   style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "20px")
  ),
  plotLines = list(
   list(label = list(text = ""),
        color = "#FF4040",
        width = 3,
        value = median(dfo$`Umbral`)
   )
  )
 ) %>%
 hc_exporting (
  enabled = TRUE
 ) %>%
 hc_add_theme(
  hc_theme_tufte()
 )
hc
```

1. Tratar los **valores extremos**, en este momento un valor extremo impide la visualización adecuada del gráfico, podría excluir con R, pero sería mejor que estuviera oculto en el gráfico, pudiendo incorporarlo mediante la leyenda donde se muestran todos los municipios.
2. Mostrar en un color diferente uno de los municipios.
3. Las dataLabels muestran una de las variables `Umbral`, pero debería ser la variable `Municipio`.
4. El tooltip actualmente muestra los valores de cada municipio, pero se deberían mostrar como una tabla incorporando los nombres de las variables, `Esfuerzo` `Umbral` `Relevancia` `Municipio`
5. La leyenda con los municipios debería estar inicialmente oculta y con un `button` poder mostrarla u ocultarla.
6. Incorporar el valor de la mediana al texto de las líneas `plotLine`
7. Poder añadir uno o varios texto cuya posición esté referenciada a la vez a los ejes (x,y).

El dataframe utilizado para poder recuperarlo con `dget()`:

```
structure(list(Código = c("02003", "03014", "04013", "05019", 
"06015", "07040", "08019", "09059", "10037", "11012", "12040", 
"13034", "14021", "15030", "16078", "17079", "18087", "19130", 
"21041", "22125", "23050", "24089", "25120", "26089", "27028", 
"28079", "29067", "30030", "32054", "33044", "34120", "35016", 
"36038", "37274", "38038", "39075", "40194", "41091", "42173", 
"43148", "44216", "45168", "46250", "47186", "49275", "50297", 
"51001", "52001"), Municipio = c("Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant", 
"Almería", "Ávila", "Badajoz", "Palma", "Barcelona", "Burgos", 
"Cáceres", "Cádiz", "Castellón de la Plana/Castelló de la Plana", 
"Ciudad Real", "Córdoba", "Coruña (A)", "Cuenca", "Girona", "Granada", 
"Guadalajara", "Huelva", "Huesca", "Jaén", "León", "Lleida", 
"Logroño", "Lugo", "Madrid", "Málaga", "Murcia", "Ourense", "Oviedo", 
"Palencia", "Palmas de Gran Canaria (Las)", "Pontevedra", "Salamanca", 
"Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Santander", "Segovia", "Sevilla", 
"Soria", "Tarragona", "Teruel", "Toledo", "Valencia", "Valladolid", 
"Zamora", "Zaragoza", "Ceuta", "Melilla"), Esfuerzo = c(66.255518296917, 
55.4505971732305, 67.3396882117212, 159.444527678894, 39.9208624778303, 
75.6407281816124, 191.885593614053, 66.4060669160645, 41.5696869168135, 
131.928027073733, 70.8156033699513, 63.3576317305502, 99.9022751874716, 
92.1737310681322, 38.5831640425687, 91.7932459374022, 108.74338544486, 
42.8257587497772, 67.209950935465, 52.5816548264175, 102.778140636216, 
81.7958449372392, 87.2101693767431, 82.8515582299525, 64.2431323026685, 
116.244125268106, 95.4495291756444, 57.9232964761993, 74.9121459540308, 
75.0079722742974, 72.345751914009, 131.407698477426, 37.4719669533452, 
70.9266085324988, 119.707963542996, 56.4080210059843, 76.5130914290131, 
102.864800169414, 155.927878655384, 96.0587342879086, 57.0368704204712, 
43.3062216835242, 83.7300653585645, 68.8468635870744, 57.9772431037523, 
112.835558277614, 189.188525288669, 431.185251161171), Relevancia = c(0.0779438999416286, 
0.075567624299619, 0.0830963177638657, 0.181216919752304, 0.0645578573307309, 
0.0694739535415282, 0.11238222267336, 0.0591312044270579, 0.0549171188507039, 
0.107335017649502, 0.0672279971174195, 0.0622048291208239, 0.106492447121433, 
0.0989219226252717, 0.0434299324062133, 0.080124826578867, 0.0923126527122762, 
0.055862728725791, 0.0816954005957221, 0.0569671724881646, 0.0902113572693082, 
0.0760249770659709, 0.0786282259767798, 0.0920644595378507, 0.0827523660072055, 
0.0869155856787086, 0.0892429670963684, 0.0705333155849015, 0.0852996555846074, 
0.069397881679441, 0.0843127745258698, 0.151586054295292, 0.0464492613233081, 
0.0720415327066066, 0.119890097237675, 0.0503879549782981, 0.0624360563921389, 
0.0965284452003263, 0.159516287787606, 0.0739061270776166, 0.0694730992371514, 
0.0410407530273502, 0.0855901086450992, 0.0787793734678359, 0.0688139147586614, 
0.102143947795215, 0.0634263210053491, 0.149047512460091), Umbral = c(21, 
28.8, 30.3, 19.2, 24.4, 16.8, 15.4, 12.8, 19.4, 20.3, 20.7, 18.6, 
24.6, 16.5, 19.4, 18.2, 24.8, 16.8, 26.5, 16.2, 20.5, 16.9, 21.4, 
16.5, 19.3, 17.3, 27.9, 24, 19.8, 16.7, 15.1, 25.6, 19.9, 20.5, 
27, 17.8, 18.2, 24.9, 13.6, 19.3, 13.1, 14.5, 21.6, 15.1, 20.4, 
14.9, 34.8, 37)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L
))
```

Comment: **6. Valor de la mediana:** text = paste("mediana ", format(median(dfau$`Umbral`), digits = 2, nsmall = 2, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","), sep="")

Comment: **2. Color diferente uno de los municipios:** hcaes(color = ifelse(dfau$Municipio == "Murcia", "#C31A00", "#8673A1"))

Comment: **3. Los municipios como dataLabels:** `format='{series.name}'`